# Security using Elasticsearch and X-pack in Angular 2/5

Tags: javascript, angular, elasticsearch, frontend

I'm new to anything to do with user authentication in general, both front and backend. I'm looking in to building an application that uses Elasticsearch with Angular 2/5. There's not a lot of information (I've found some) about how to build an Angular 2+ app with Elasticsearch, particularly in regards to authentication, and user role management. But researching how to accomplish this, I've found [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial) by Jason Watmore that I will try to adapt to Elastic. I see in the comments, Jason explains that for sites where you want the front-end to be secure, it is advisable to do authentication in a separate front-end app, and then redirect the user to the full app, once the user has logged in. The reason being that no front-end app is secure, in that a user could alter variables to view routes that are protected by route guards, or other ways. That data is still secure from the back-end, but you have features you don't want the public knowing about in the front-end, like how you are analyzing data entered by users.

My first (but secondary) question is, in regards securing a front-end application, is this an absolute truth that it isn't possible? It makes sense, and I have a hunch it is true, but I was wondering if there are ways to at least make it very difficult to view guarded routes. (Like the route guard asks the server if the token is valid?... But then you could just mod the function to always return true, right? Hmm...)

Anyways, it's looking like my application will need three parts in lieu of this. The login/registration, the public side where the standard route guards are sufficient, and an admin that will need to be entirely hidden from the public.

<strike>With Elasticsearch, (I think) there's an opportunity to develop our application entirely without backend coding, since X-pack provides security and features for managing user roles... Except for maybe one thing: I'm not sure how to keep the front-end of the admin from the public. Will this require some backend work?</strike> **Update:** This was what someone else was telling me early on. It isn't true.

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. Different people will have different knowledge and be able to answer 1 or your questions well, but not the others. In order to get the best possible answers to your questions, you should separate them into clear stand-alone questions that can be answered independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With Elasticsearch, (I think) there's an opportunity to develop our application entirely without backend coding, since X-pack provides security and features for managing user roles.

It's possible, but not recommended. The Elasticsearch API is not designed to be consumed directly by a front end client, and the security constraints that are put in place within X-Pack do not aim to be secure within that environment.
Elastic recommends that you communicate with Elasticsearch from a backend process.

There are elasticsearch clients for many languages including python and node, so you can use whatever backend technology you prefer.